# Chrome Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL

Tags: html, extjs, sencha-touch, aptana, sencha-touch-2

I keep getting this error:  Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL while running Ext JS 4, I'm using Sencha Touch 2 on Aptana studio 3.

Here's my code:

Ext.application({
        name: 'Sencha',
        launch: function () {

```
        Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            defaults: {
                styleHtmlContent: true
            },

            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Home Page',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    html: [
                        '<img width="30%" src="http://staging.sencha.com/img/sencha.png" />',
                        '<h1>Welcome to Sencha Touch</h1>',
                        "<p>you're creating the Getting Started app. This demonstrates how ",
                        "to use tabs, lists and forms to create a simple app</p>",
                        '<h2>Sencha Touch 2 </h2>
                    ].join("")
                }
            ]

        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Try JSLint, it can help find javascript bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing '

`'<h2>Sencha Touch 2 </h2>'`